# Magento causes deadlock in mariadb

Tags: mysql, magento, mariadb

My Magento(Vesion 1.8.0.0) website was running without any problem when I was using MySQL5.5 database for years. After moving to mariadb-server-10.2 recently(exported data using sqldump and then imported on new mariadb server), many times PHP child process stays in waiting states until max_execution_time expires and finally php-fpm stops responding.

On investigation I found that all the php child processes are waiting on database queries. I checked the processlist on mariadb when I encountered the problem recently and output is below. Any idea how I could fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
    MariaDB [(none)]> show processlist;
+--------+-------------+-------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------                            --------------------------------+----------+
| Id     | User        | Host                          | db      | Command | Time | State                        | Info                                                                                                                             | Progress |
+--------+-------------+-------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------                            --------------------------------+----------+
|      1 | system user |                               | NULL    | Daemon  | NULL |                              | NULL                                                                                                                             |    0.000 |
|      2 | system user |                               | NULL    | Daemon  | NULL |                              | NULL                                                                                                                             |    0.000 |
|      4 | system user |                               | NULL    | Daemon  | NULL |                              | NULL                                                                                                                             |    0.000 |
|      3 | system user |                               | NULL    | Daemon  | NULL |                              | NULL                                                                                                                             |    0.000 |
|      5 | system user |                               | NULL    | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB shutdown handler      | NULL                                                                                                                             |    0.000 |
| 109822 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:56405 | catalog | Query   |  985 | update                       | INSERT INTO `cataloginventory_stock_status` (`product_id`,`website_id                            `,`stock_id`,`qty`,`stock_statu |    0.000 |
| 109850 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:56436 | catalog | Query   |  985 | update                       | INSERT INTO `cataloginventory_stock_status` (`product_id`,`website_id                            `,`stock_id`,`qty`,`stock_statu |    0.000 |
| 109859 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:56448 | catalog | Query   |  985 | update                       | INSERT INTO `cataloginventory_stock_status` (`product_id`,`website_id                            `,`stock_id`,`qty`,`stock_statu |    0.000 |
| 109931 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:56554 | catalog | Query   |  986 | Waiting for table level lock | DELETE FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` WHERE (store_id=1) AND (product_                            id IN ('26515'))                |    0.000 |
| 109966 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:56606 | catalog | Query   |  984 | Waiting for table level lock | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 33218 AS `query_id`, `s`.`p                            roduct_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FR |    0.000 |
| 109993 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:56645 | catalog | Query   |  934 | update                       | INSERT INTO `sales_flat_quote_item` (`quote_id`, `created_at`, `updat                            ed_at`, `product_id`, `store_id |    0.000 |
| 109997 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:56650 | catalog | Query   |  987 | Sending data                 | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 33215 AS `query_id`, `s`.`p                            roduct_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FR |    0.000 |
| 110040 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:56709 | catalog | Query   |  983 | Waiting for table level lock | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 33215 AS `query_id`, `s`.`p                            roduct_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FR |    0.000 |
| 110218 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:56925 | catalog | Query   |  940 | Waiting for table level lock | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 6656 AS `query_id`, `s`.`pr                            oduct_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FRO |    0.000 |
| 110248 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:56956 | catalog | Query   |  932 | Waiting for table level lock | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 33220 AS `query_id`, `s`.`p                            roduct_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FR |    0.000 |
| 110380 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:57095 | catalog | Query   |  906 | Waiting for table level lock | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 33214 AS `query_id`, `s`.`p                            roduct_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FR |    0.000 |
| 110392 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:57107 | catalog | Query   |  905 | Waiting for table level lock | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 33215 AS `query_id`, `s`.`p                            roduct_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FR |    0.000 |
| 110810 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:57554 | catalog | Query   |  825 | Waiting for table level lock | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 6656 AS `query_id`, `s`.`pr                            oduct_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FRO |    0.000 |
| 110865 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:57616 | catalog | Query   |  808 | Waiting for table level lock | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 21581 AS `query_id`, `s`.`p                            roduct_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FR |    0.000 |
| 110968 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:57782 | catalog | Query   |   48 | update                       | INSERT INTO `sales_flat_quote_item` (`quote_id`, `created_at`, `updat                            ed_at`, `product_id`, `store_id |    0.000 |
| 110969 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:57783 | catalog | Query   |   48 | update                       | INSERT INTO `sales_flat_quote_item` (`quote_id`, `created_at`, `updat                            ed_at`, `product_id`, `store_id |    0.000 |
| 110989 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:57803 | catalog | Query   |   39 | update                       | INSERT INTO `sales_flat_quote_item` (`quote_id`, `created_at`, `updat                            ed_at`, `product_id`, `store_id |    0.000 |
| 110999 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:57813 | catalog | Query   |   34 | update                       | INSERT INTO `sales_flat_quote_item` (`quote_id`, `created_at`, `updat                            ed_at`, `product_id`, `store_id |    0.000 |
| 111012 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:57867 | catalog | Query   |   32 | update                       | INSERT INTO `sales_flat_quote_item` (`quote_id`, `created_at`, `updat                            ed_at`, `product_id`, `store_id |    0.000 |
| 111067 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:57959 | catalog | Query   |   18 | update                       | INSERT INTO `sales_flat_quote_item` (`quote_id`, `created_at`, `updat                            ed_at`, `product_id`, `store_id |    0.000 |
| 111077 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:57974 | catalog | Query   |   15 | update                       | INSERT INTO `sales_flat_quote_item` (`quote_id`, `created_at`, `updat                            ed_at`, `product_id`, `store_id |    0.000 |
| 111078 | root        | localhost                     | NULL    | Query   |    0 | init                         | show processlist                                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 111117 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:58015 | catalog | Query   |   10 | Waiting for table level lock | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 13226 AS `query_id`, `s`.`p                            roduct_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FR |    0.000 |
| 111147 | moodle      | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:58046 | moodle  | Sleep   |    0 |                              | NULL                                                                                                                             |    0.000 |
+--------+-------------+-------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------                            --------------------------------+----------+
29 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**#update2**
'Show create table output' of table's in waiting state is as below

```
MariaDB [catalog]> SHOW CREATE TABLE catalogsearch_fulltext;
+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                  | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| catalogsearch_fulltext | CREATE TABLE `catalogsearch_fulltext` (
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Product ID',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store ID',
  `data_index` longtext DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Data index',
  `fulltext_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`fulltext_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CATALOGSEARCH_FULLTEXT_PRODUCT_ID_STORE_ID` (`product_id`,`store_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `FTI_CATALOGSEARCH_FULLTEXT_DATA_INDEX` (`data_index`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=912741 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog search result table' |
+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [catalog]> SHOW CREATE TABLE catalogsearch_result;
+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| catalogsearch_result | CREATE TABLE `catalogsearch_result` (
  `query_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Query ID',
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Product ID',
  `relevance` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0000 COMMENT 'Relevance',
  PRIMARY KEY (`query_id`,`product_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOGSEARCH_RESULT_QUERY_ID` (`query_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOGSEARCH_RESULT_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOGSEARCH_RESULT_QUERY_ID_CATALOGSEARCH_QUERY_QUERY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`query_id`) REFERENCES `catalogsearch_query` (`query_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CATSRCH_RESULT_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog search result table' |
+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table mentioned with a "table level lock".

Comment: @RickJames, I have updated the question with the 'SHOW CREATE TABLE' output of two tables which are waiting for 'table level lock'

Comment: I checked the 'SHOW CREATE TABLE' of the table 'cataloginventory_stock_status' also. It is using InnoDB. Does the usage of different engine's caused the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process with the most time (#109997) is touching that MyISAM table?  After doing `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`, I see

```
INSERT
     INTO  `catalogsearch_result` 
SELECT  11474 AS `query_id`, `s`.`product_id`, 0 AS `relevance`
    FROM  `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s`
    INNER JOIN  `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`  ON e.entity_id = s.product_id
    WHERE  (s.store_id = 1)
      AND  ((`s`.`data_index` LIKE '%Informaatika%'
         OR  `s`.`data_index` LIKE '%8.c%')
           )  ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE  `relevance` = VALUES(`relevance`)
```

That is a slow `SELECT` that only recently got started.  Since we are talking about MyISAM, and there writes going on, the queries will happen one at a time (mostly).

It is slow because of both the `OR` and the *leading* wildcard in the `LIKE` test.  Do you have any way to avoid *both* of those issues?  With them there, the `SELECT` must scan the entire table, which apparently takes minutes.  (How big is the table?)

Changing timeouts may get you past one instance, but then simply keep you in a never-ending sequence of queries waiting for other queries to finish.

The best solution is to get away from MyISAM.  More tips on that:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

(Even after converting, there could be other issues.)

Comment: Since I can not put the output of 'Show full processlist' here, I put it in git hub - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4c2d6bfe8b45bcf4fed60f225f251075

Comment: The insert query you asked is  INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 6656 AS `query_id`, `s`.`product_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = s.product_id WHERE (s.store_id = 1) AND ((`s`.`data_index` LIKE '%informaatika%')) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `relevance` = VALUES(`relevance`)

Comment: Will setting any timeout values like 'lock_wait_timeout' fix the isssue? Now the timeout value is pretty big - 86400 which is default.

Comment: I mostly rewrote my answer, based on the full query.

Comment: Yes the table 'catalogsearch_fulltext' has 18998 records and all of them has store_id=1. And data_index is pretty big for each of the records. So as you found out it is going to be very slow sql operation. What I don't understand is, why I did not face these problems when I was using MySQL. Some default settings in MySQL was saving me. Thanks for the answer. I will ask Magento people how to get rid of this query.

Comment: I asked a question in magento.stackexchage regarding how to get rid of this slow query - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192573/deadlock-caused-by-slow-query

Comment: As long as you are using MyISAM, this _might_ help:  `OPTIMIZE TABLE catalogsearch_result;`

Comment: As for getting help from Magento, I think you will need to explain what your dataset is about and what "8.c" means, etc.

Comment: Rajeev was there ever any resolution to this problem you have?? I'm having the same / similar issue.